# Python 3.6: rename column header using DictWriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, ordereddictionary

my python script currently uses DictWriter to read a csv file, re-arrange the columns and write to a new output csv file. The input CSV file has the following columns:

```
A;B;C;D
```

which will be transferred to:

```
B,C;A;D
```

Additionally, I would like to rename one of the header. I already tried 2 approaches:

1.) create a new `writer` object and use the `writer' method. However, this simply puts all the given fieldnames in the very first columns:

```
newHeader = csv.writer(outfile)
newFN = ['B', 'C', 'Renamed', 'D']
newHeader.writerow(newFN)
```

the output is:

```
B,C,Renamed,D;;;
```

2.) Using the existing `DictWriter` object I define a new list of column headers and iterate over it:

```
newHeader = ['B', 'C', 'Renamed', 'D']
writer.writerow(dict((fn, fn) for fn in newHeader))
```

This time however, the renamed column header remains empty in the output CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can use a dictionary to rename columns and `csv.writer` to write values from reordered `OrderedDict` objects:

```
from io import StringIO
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv

mystr = StringIO("""A;B;C;D
1;2;3;4
5;6;7;8""")

order = ['B', 'C', 'A', 'D']

# define renamed columns via dictionary
renamer = {'C': 'C2'}

# define column names after renaming
new_cols = [renamer.get(x, x) for x in order]

# replace mystr as open(r'file.csv', 'r')
with mystr as fin, open(r'C:\temp\out.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout:

    # define reader / writer objects
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter=';')
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=';')

    # write new header
    writer.writerow(new_cols)

    # iterate reader and write row
    for item in reader:
        writer.writerow([item[k] for k in order])
```

Result:

```
B;C2;A;D
2;3;1;4
6;7;5;8
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.